# Jmeter Oracle JDBC issue : ORA-09945: Unable to initialize the audit trail file

Tags: oracle, jmeter, ojdbc

I am trying to connect to Oracle DB from Jmeter yet I receive the error below

> java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory
> (ORA-09945: Unable to initialize the audit trail file Linux-x86_64
> Error: 28: No space left on device ORA-00604: error occurred at
> recursive SQL level 1 ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or
> invalid environment specified )

- Apache Jmeter 5.3
- ojdbc14 jar in **/lib** folder
- Database URL : jdbc:oracle:thin@IP:PORT:SID
- JDBC Driver Class : oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

How to solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, sir, you're really asking how to solve `No space left on device` issue on StackOverflow?

How about:

- [extending a partition](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1190213)
- mounting an [NFS share](https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/azure-anf-blg-linux-nfs-server-how-to-set-up-server-and-client)
- **or just deleting the file(s) you don't need**

Looking into your setup I can see a couple of potential problems as well, i.e.

- `Apache Jmeter 5.3`: as per [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.4.3](https://lists.apache.org/thread/dbg1bxywcwx5vtdwqf8ownf7ppgqjn41) (or whatever is the latest stable version which is available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)
- `ojdbc14` indicates that the driver has been built for [Java 14](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/14/) and it's support ended on 30 Sep 2020, I believe you should not be using it so consider upgrading to Java 17 (or alternatively downgrading to Java 11)

Answer (score 0):

ojdbc14 is a very old version. You should use either 21c or 19c version of the Oracle JDBC driver. ojdbc8.jar or ojdbc11.jar. Check out the [JDBC download page](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html) for the latest versions.